# Different algorithms count tag's score: Desktop SO vs Mobile SO

Tags: discussion, tag-score

What is the difference in algorithms counting tag's score: mobile vs desktop?

[image]

They are extremely different!

[image]

Comment: It seems to be including your question scores (you have 30 questions with a score of 29)

Comment: But I have more that 29 points for questions' score. Look at my questions.

Comment: In the desktop version just hover over the score, it should show you how many questions and answer you have in that tag and the score.

Comment: I saw it but I suppose this count is wrong too.